# Digital signed PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, certificate

I'm trying to digitaly sign PDF document with PHP. I have bought certificate (not using self-signed). What I've got is CER and PEM file. I've tried to generate signed PDF using TCPDF library but with no success. The perfect solution would be to just add signature to existing document (pdf). Any advice?