# Create a digitally signed pdf document in yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii2, pdf-generation

I want to create a pdf document which should be digitally signed upon creation in yii2 framework (Kartik grid view). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, go ahead and create it. What's the question or the trouble you're having?

Comment: Any suggestions how to create that as I am new in this

Comment: Have you searched on the Internet and through this resource?

Comment: Have you tried a web search for "add digital signature to pdf in php"? There's lot's of information out there, and on this site.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't understood how to implement them.I go through the "setasign" and also this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096261/digital-signed-pdf-with-php

Comment: all are giving like scan an image of signature and put in pdf, but I dont want that. I want something like which is implemented in form16.

Comment: An Idea : Make user upload signature in image or something like that, render image in pdf.

Comment: No, I don't want to do like that image procedure. I want it like, the one used in form 16 or it should look like digital signature in pdf documents

Comment: Any suggestions please for creating a pdf document with the digital signature in php (yii2 framework)